# What service can I use to verify a checking account?

Tags: web-services, banking

My user enters in their routing and account number as well as their bank website login credentials. I want to send that info to an API that tells me whether it's valid. Coinbase for instance uses such a service when you add an account (but they won't disclose which service they use).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yodlee

http://interactive.yodlee.com/products/iav-api

and Intuit

https://developer.intuit.com/us#CustomerAccountDataAPI

I chose the latter, because I read that they're easier to integrate with and have lower pricing.